# Most efficient/ clean way to create a matrix out of a list of lists under certain conditions?

Tags: python, list, time, comparison, midi

Also this is my first time posting on here, so sorry if I mess anything up. I wasn't sure what to title this, but my project for class  but I brute forced my way out of a problem today and was wondering if anyone had a more efficient way to do what I needed. I spent a good 2 hours working on it and would love to see how you guys would tackle it.

**Background**: Using the midi library, you can extract the musical notes of an audio track along with when they are played. After some work you get something like this:

```
notes = ['B3', 'C4', 'G2', 'G3', 'B3', 'D4', 'F4', 'G2', 'D4', 'F4']
ticks = [0, 1, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 22, 22,]
```

A tick is basically the time domain for midi. It represents when that note plays for the first time and the list `ticks` corresponds to `notes` (`notes[0]` plays at time `ticks[0]`). For my purposes, I can only play a note through 1 of 4 devices at once. So when I have repeating ticks I need to play a *chord*, or multiple notes at once. By default, one note gets played by device(channel0) one, two notes get played by channel1, and so on...

e.g. the above track would be played like this;

- channel0 plays B3 at t=0
- channel0 plays C4 at t=1
- channels0,1 & 2 play G2,G3 & B3 at t=12
- channels0 & 1 play D4 & F4 at t=15
- channels0,1 & 2 play G2, D4 & F4 at t=22

**Problem**: Given `notes` and `ticks`, create instructions for channels 0-3 with the correct timing and notes. If a chord has more than 4 notes, I simply omit them because theres not much I can do with them. Basically, I needed the data structure to look like the one below:

```
channel0 = ['B3', 'C4', 'G2', 'D4']
channel1 = [  0,    0,  'G3', 'F4']
channel2 = [  0,    0,  'B3',   0 ]
channel3 = [  0,    0,    0,    0 ]
```

I first attempted to brute force it with a monstrosity that was a bunch of if statements, but ultimately came up with this.

**Solution**: First, I created a list of tuples to compare how many times each tick occured in the track, but that was pointless. I just made it an array.

```
res = []
for i in ticks:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
counts = [(ticks.count(x)) for x in res]
```

Then, I made a list of lists for the channels. I ordered them backwards because it was easier to work the "matrix" bottom to top.

```
ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3 = ([] for i in range(4))
final = [ch3, ch2, ch1, ch0]
```

Finally, this shameful thing somehow worked.

```
    countsidx = -1
    while breakMe:
        countsidx += 1
        for finalidx, vchan in enumerate(final):
            if int(finalidx) >= counts[countsidx]:
                vchan.append(0)
            else:
                vchan.append(notes[notesidx])
                notesidx += 1
            if notesidx == len(notes):
                return final
                breakMe = False
    return final
```

So my question is: how could I have done this with less code? Does anyone have an easier way to do the same thing I did? I love learning best practices. I feel like I spent way too much time on this simple thing.

**Full code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import sys
import collections
from mido import MidiFile
from midiutil import MIDIFile
import sys

NOTES = ['C', 'CS', 'D', 'DS', 'E', 'F', 'FS', 'G', 'GS', 'A', 'AS', 'B']
OCTAVES = list(range(11))
NOTES_IN_OCTAVE = len(NOTES)

def countShit(ticks,notes):
    breakMe = True
    res = []
    for i in ticks:
        if i not in res:
            res.append(i)
    counts = [(ticks.count(x)) for x in res]
    print('Counts (ticks,occurences) == ', counts)
    ch0,ch1,ch2,ch3, = ([] for i in range(4))
    final =[ch3,ch2,ch1,ch0]
    notesidx = 0
    countsidx = -1
    while breakMe:
        countsidx += 1
        for finalidx, vchan in enumerate(final):
            if int(finalidx) >= counts[countsidx]:
                vchan.append(0)
            else:
                vchan.append(notes[notesidx])
                notesidx += 1
            if notesidx == len(notes):
                return final
                breakMe = False
    return final

def convertTuple(tup):
    str =  ''.join(tup)
    return str

def number_to_note(number: int) -> tuple:
    octave = number // NOTES_IN_OCTAVE
    assert octave in OCTAVES, errors['notes']
    assert 0 <= number <= 127, errors['notes']
    note = NOTES[number % NOTES_IN_OCTAVE]
    return str(note),str(octave-2)

song = midi.read_midifile('mario_06.mid')
song.make_ticks_abs()
tracks =[]
trackNotes =[]
trackTime = []
trackTicks=[]
for track in song:
    notes = [note for note in track if note.name == 'Note On']
    notes2 = [note for note in track if note.name == 'Note Off']
    pitch = [note.pitch for note in notes]
    tick = [note.tick for note in notes]
    trackTime =[b.tick - a.tick for a,b in zip(notes,notes2)]
    tracks += [tick, pitch]
    trackNotes += pitch
    trackTicks += tick


trackNotesFinal =[]
for i in trackNotes:
    k = str(convertTuple(number_to_note(i)))
    trackNotesFinal.append(k)

trackNotesFinal
channels = countShit(trackTicks,trackNotesFinal)
```

Comment: This looks clean even though it is long. I think there is not a learning opportunity here or a practice that you could abide by (other than naming your functions a little nicer). One thing I personally would do would make sure my loop runs at a constant speed and use import time so that it is easier to keep track of how long a song has been playing/when to skip etc.

Comment: I think you might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this question.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using list comprehensions, with `zip` and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). I assume that the `ticks` array is always in order.

```py
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

NUM_CHANNELS = 4

chords = [
    [ note for _, note in chord ]
    for _, chord in itertools.groupby(zip(ticks, notes), key=itemgetter(0))
]
# [['B3'], ['C4'], ['G2', 'G3', 'B3'], ['D4', 'F4'], ['G2', 'D4']]

channels = [
    [ chord[i] if i < len(chord) else None for chord in chords ]
    for i in range(NUM_CHANNELS)
]
# [['B3', 'C4', 'G2', 'D4', 'G2'],
#  [None, None, 'G3', 'F4', 'D4'],
#  [None, None, 'B3', None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

I've used `None` instead of `0` for the absence of a note, since that is more Pythonic (and as a bonus, makes the matrix columns line up nicely when printed).

Since you will probably also want to know the timings for each column in the matrix, this can be done with another list comprehension:

```py
timings = [ tick for tick, _ in itertools.groupby(ticks) ]
# [0, 1, 12, 15, 22]
```